# jquery datepicker only inserting one date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, servicenow

I created a form that has many datepickers, but when testing, no matter what date I choose, it always enters 12/13/2016 into the table. Here's my code, I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write all this, but this is what I managed to piece together with my elementary knowledge of JS:

```
var $j_custom = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    $j_custom( function() {
            $j_custom( "#fromRow1" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow1" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow2" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow2" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow3" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow3" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow4" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow4" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow5" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow5" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow6" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow6" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow7" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow7" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#fromRow8" ).datepicker();
            $j_custom( "#toRow8" ).datepicker();
              } );

document.addEventListener("submit", submitRequest);
function submitRequest() {
var gr = new GlideRecord('x_81991_federal_hc_sf_144');
gr.initialize();
    gr.agency_from_1 = document.getElementById('fromRow1').value;
    gr.agency_from_2 = document.getElementById('fromRow2').value;
    gr.agency_from_3 = document.getElementById('fromRow3').value;
    gr.agency_from_4 = document.getElementById('fromRow4').value;
    gr.agency_from_5 = document.getElementById('fromRow5').value;
    gr.agency_from_6 = document.getElementById('fromRow6').value;
    gr.agency_from_7 = document.getElementById('fromRow7').value;
    gr.agency_from_8 = document.getElementById('fromRow8').value;
    gr.agency_to_1 = document.getElementById('toRow1').value;
    gr.agency_to_2 = document.getElementById('toRow2').value;
    gr.agency_to_3 = document.getElementById('toRow3').value;
    gr.agency_to_4 = document.getElementById('toRow4').value;
    gr.agency_to_5 = document.getElementById('toRow5').value;
    gr.agency_to_6 = document.getElementById('toRow6').value;
    gr.agency_to_7 = document.getElementById('toRow7').value;
    gr.agency_to_8 = document.getElementById('toRow8').value;
gr.insert();
}
```

No matter what dates I enter, all i see is this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?  Thanks!!

Comment: show us your insert() as well

Comment: Hi @TechBreak, what do you mean by show you my insert()?

Comment: i assumer your insert() is setting value in your datepicker after you select? or you want to see current date on page load ?

Comment: ohh, on page load, the form is blank.  yes I would like the user to be able to select a date and for the chosen date to be inserted into my table onSubmit.

Comment: so you database dont have selected value you mean? check if those values were passed and stored in the database.

Comment: can you put up a fiddle so we can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: hi @mrid, yes: https://jsfiddle.net/yundlu/4uw78rcx/

Comment: @Dave, it's filling the correct ( values I selected in the datepicker ) in the textbox. Can you show us the code you are using to insert data into your database ?

Comment: hi @mrid, I'm using the onSubmit event listener to initialize a new record.  Then I'm assigning each database field equal to its corresponding form field by using document.getElementById().value;  I think the code is presented above.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @Dave, yea thanks, i'll go through it

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a library for this, it might help you:

```
$(function(){
    $(".select2").select2();
    //Datemask dd/mm/yyyy
    $("#datemask").inputmask("dd/mm/yyyy", {"placeholder": "dd/mm/yyyy"});
    //Datemask2 mm/dd/yyyy
    $("#datemask2").inputmask("mm/dd/yyyy", {"placeholder": "mm/dd/yyyy"});
    //Money Euro
    $("[data-mask]").inputmask();

    //Date range picker
    $('#reservation').daterangepicker();
    //Date range picker with time picker
    $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'});
    //Date range as a button
    $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
        {
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            },
            startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
            endDate: moment()
        },
        function (start, end) {
            $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }
    );

    //Date picker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    });
```

In addition to JQuery, Get the Bootstrap-datepicker.js.

Someone created a free template that includes such functionality, and the code is free:

[AdminLTE Template](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/advanced.html)